# IBM Worklight - Plugin installation failure in Win7/Eclipse "Juno"

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am trying to install Worklight, but the installation fails with the following.
I am using Eclipse Juno SR2

```
    Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
 Software being installed: IBM Worklight Studio 6.1.0.00-20131219-1900         (com.ibm.imp.tools.feature.feature.group 6.1.0.00-20131219-1900)
Missing requirement: Model Plug-in 8.0.0.v20131219_1846 (com.ibm.etools.webtools.model     8.0.0.v20131219_1846) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.type.core [1.0.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Web Page Generation Core Plugin 7.2.500.v20131219_1846 (com.ibm.etools.webtools.webpage.core 7.2.500.v20131219_1846)
  To: bundle com.ibm.etools.webtools.model [8.0.0,9.0.0)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: IBM Mobile Application Tools 6.1.0.00-20131219-1900 (com.ibm.imp.feature.feature.group 6.1.0.00-20131219-1900)
To: com.ibm.imp.worklight.core [6.1.0.00-20131219-1900]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: IBM Worklight Studio 6.1.0.00-20131219-1900 (com.ibm.imp.tools.feature.feature.group 6.1.0.00-20131219-1900)
 To: com.ibm.imp.feature.feature.group 6.1.0

Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: Core 6.1.0.00-20131219-1900 (com.ibm.imp.worklight.core 6.1.0.00-20131219-1900)
  To: bundle com.ibm.etools.webtools.webpage.core [7.2.0,8.0.0)
```

Comment: Are you using a zip file you've downloaded or using the Eclipse Marketplace (by searching for "worklight")?

Comment: Also make sure you are using Eclipse **Java EE** 4.2.2 ("Juno" SR2) or Eclipse **Java EE** 4.3.1 ("Kepler" SR1).

Comment: i am using marketplace

Comment: Thanks for answer Idan Adar but i want to ask you that do u have any link for directly get the worklight plugin in zip format which is working good.

Comment: If you are an IBM customer you can download the repository file from IBM Passport Advantage; Otherwise you can follow the steps once clicking the Download button at: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/index.html

Comment: The Eclipse installation for me, though. So 1) make sure you are using the Eclipse version I have mentioned above, and 2) perhaps there is a network issue, try again later.

Comment: My Eclipse version is Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426

Comment: Use this: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/SR1/eclipse-jee-kepler-SR1-win32-x86_64.zip and then install Worklight from the Marketplace. Works.

Comment: @IdanAdar Totally off topic, but any idea when IBM is going to just support Eclipse in general and not restrict users to specific version of Eclipse? I know Keppler support was enabled in 6.1 (I think, 5.0.6, 6.0, 6.1),but for the duration of my Worklight experience (maybe 6 months?) it's be Juno or nothing.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know.

Comment: I also download Juno SR1 and try to install Worklight from market place it's giving same error.please help

Comment: I already wrote that only Juno SR2 and Kepler SR1 are supported... why try with something else? Please try with the link I gave you above(!).

Comment: You keep insisting on other things; had other things been possible, we'd advise you to do them, ...

Comment: I tried with your link but it's a 64 bit link and i have the 32 bit Windows 7 OS;so i download 32 bit juno Kepler SR1 and tried.May be possible i download the wrong SR1 package but it's give me the conflicting error rather then dependency.I tried IBM Worklight Developer Edition from Eclipse Market place.

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr1

Answer (score 0):

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devenv/t_installing_ibm_worklight_studi.html

Just make sure that you've met the system requirements, and make the proper installation.

Comment: Can you provide me the zip file link of this plugin like ADT zip in Android.

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr2       Look at the right side of your window, then decide if your a windows user, MAC oS x or Linux, either 32-bit/64-bit @KDOSHI

Comment: I am talking about IBM Worklight plugin not an Eclipse. I am already using a Eclipse Juno SR2 version

Comment: sorry for that   http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/   just press on the download button and then it will direct you to a webpage then fill the required fields...click submit, and follow those steps...

Comment: I already done this but there is no direct link in that.It shows the information which I already done.One more thing i tried that I install the worklight workbench for mobile in eclipse juno sr2.It was successfully completed.

Comment: @KDOSHI The eclipse marketplace has the current version of the worklight developer edition